# Do I use set or sets in this sentence?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Luxurious detailing, such as chrome-accented hardware and rich suede fabric, set a new style standard in travelware.

Comment: Your subject "detailing" is singular, so if you are going for the simple present, use "sets." However, the simple past of "to set" is also "set." So, if you are going for the simple past, use "set."

Comment: Welcome, Laura, please take the site [tour]. General proofreading is off-topic here. If you have a specific question about the use of *set* and if you describe what you have found in your research so far, the question will probably get more attention.

Answer (score 2):

Set as you've used it is making reference to something that happened and marked a change that resulted in a new, recognized, and adhered to result.

Sets is present tense and is referring to something that is happening and/or ongoing

Answer (score 0):

You should say sets because its saying that it is doing that now, but if you say set it would be saying that it would set in the future.

Comment: "Set" is either the plural simple present or the simple past, not the future. Future tense would be "will set."

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context, are you referring to something that happened in the past, or the present?

> ***On the Titanic***, luxurious detailing, such as chrome-accented hardware and rich suede fabric, ***set*** a new style standard in travel ware.
>
> (***In an infomercial***) Luxurious detailing, such as chrome-accented hardware and rich suede fabric, ***sets*** a new style standard in travelware.